# Content does not reflect on CD server after publishing from CM server

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore7.2, web-publishing

When a content is published from Content Management server to Content Delivery server, the publishing activity is inconsistent, i.e., sometimes the content reflects on CD server in couple of minutes or takes a whole day. The only scenario where the content reflects  immediately on CD server is by restarting the application pool, but this is not the best practice as content editing can be frequent and every time restarting the app pool may crash the application. Please suggest what other measures can be taken, to get this issue resolved

Comment: Sounds like your cache clearing is not set up correctly. Check the 'publish:end:remote' config setting and if your 'site' is anything other than the default website then add it.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have scalability settings enabled.

Also, did you configure the Html Cache Clearer?

```
  <event name="publish:end">
    <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
      <sites hint="list">
        <site>website</site>
      </sites>
    </handler>
  </event>
  <event name="publish:end:remote">
    <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.HtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache">
      <sites hint="list">
        <site>website</site>
      </sites>
    </handler>
  </event>
```